# Doctrine load relations from an Arraycollection

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm looking for an elegant way to do the following:

Lets say I have an Entity with a OneToMany Relation, e.g.

```
class Parent
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Child")
     */
    private $children;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->children = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}

class Child
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Parent")
     */
    private $parent;
}
```

Now in my logic I have to filter those parents which can't be done by queries only. So I end up with an ArrayCollection of parents, e.g:

```
$parents = new ArrayCollection([
    $parent1,
    $parent2,
    $parent3
]);
```

Now from all those parents, I would like to join the children with one query.
How could I do this with doctrine.

I know I could just loop over the collection and call `->getChildren()` on each parent.

But I possibly have hundreds of parents (which would mean hundreds of queries). Which I would like to avoid.

Before anyone says 'do a LEFT JOIN on the parents when you get them', I cannot filter the parents I need with only queries. So this is why I cannot just LEFT JOIN.

Cookies for thoughs !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid the [N + 1 selects problem](https://www.google.de/search?q=n%20%2B%201%20select), I would suggest the following solution which doesn’t need JOINs and uses two separate queries. This is the most efficient solution.

First, retrieve all parents:

```
$parents = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select("p")
    ->from("YourFoobarBundle:Parent", "p")
    ->where(/*...*/)
    ->setParameter(/*...*/)
    ->indexBy("p.id")
    ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Now load all children of those parents:

```
$children = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select("c")
    ->from("YourFoobarBundle:Child", "c")
    ->where("IDENTITY(child.parent) IN (?1)")
    ->setParameter(1, array_keys($parents))
    ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

The great thing about Doctrine is that now all needed entities are stored in memory. So when you do a `$parent->getChildren()`, you don’t trigger a new DB query (unless the children have additional relations themselves).

NOTE: If you *always* need all children of the selected parents, you should mark the `$children` for eager loading:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Child", fetch="EAGER")
 */
private $children;
```

In this case, Doctrine will always (!) fetch the needed children automatically.

Comment: Great way of doing this, so doctrine will automaticly add them to the parent->getChildern(). Good to know, thank you !

Comment: @RVandersteen, No it won't add them to the parent, it will add them to your `$children` result set from your entity repository.

Comment: @lxg, nice answer, but it is not the most efficient solution; this operation can be done in one single query. Check my answer for reference.

Comment: @lxg Thanks for clarifying, it is what I understood but I guess my phrasing was incorrect (the automaticly add them to ...)

Comment: @RVandersteen: Ok, if you don’t need the parents, a single query is sufficient. However, not with a subquery, as discussed below.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a sub query and use it inside a clause (a where in expression) of your other query. It is very much like @lxg describes, but you can do all this in one single query for increased performance (You don't have to execute the queries separately).

```
$qb  = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();

$sub = $qb->select('p')
          ->from('Application\Entity\Parent', 'p')
          ->where(/*...*/)
          ->setParameter(/*...*/)

$children = $qb->select('c')
               ->from('Application\Entity\Child', 'c')
               ->where($qb->expr()->in('c.parent', $sub->getDQL()))
               ->getQuery()
               ->getResult();
```

Comment: Also good to know this trick, the problem in our case is that we need to do some additional filtering on the 'parent' (in your case sub) before getting the children. This is why we can't do it in 1 query. Thank you for your contribution

Comment: @RVandersteen, you can add the *filtering* to the sub query. Not sure why you say you cannot do it. What kind of *filtering* are you talking about? Please add the specifics to your question. If you don't add it to the question I cannot add it to the answer.

Comment: We have some complex application logic to fetch the necesarry 'parent' elements which cannot be solved by queries only. In the end we have an array / arraycollection of the 'parent' elements that satisfy these checks / filters / .. So it is not possible for us to do it in one query

Comment: What kind of complex application logic are you talking about. IMO all filtering that you can do in your application can also be done in queries. You should consider adding all relevant details to your question to get proper answers (read also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).

Comment: In the most simple form: These elements are forming chains with subchains - with conditions on those chains. (You can look at those conditions as evaluatable expressions). Although in my question I have added twice that we cannot get everything in one query, maybe you overlooked that part. Nevertheless, your answer will be usefull in other situations.

Comment: One last comment :) Evaluable expressions can also be part of your query, there is a whole list of them [here in the doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class). Use it or not use it as you please.

Comment: @Wilt: Subqueries do not perform better than two separate queries, because – well, it’s still two queries internally. Try on SQL level with `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` or similar. Also, your solution causes Doctrine to  fetch every parent separately as soon you access it from the child entity.

Comment: @lxg There is a difference between two doctrine queries and two MySQL queries. If you execute two doctrine queries you need to twice connect to your MySQL service and this additional overhead will lead to performance decrease. If you can do things in one Doctrine query it is definitely advisable to do so by all means. Eager loading the parent is not necessary in this case (I chose lazy load), you can still fetch join the parent if needed in the second query, this is up to OP.

Comment: Ok, if you really don’t need the parents, it can be done with one query. Then, still, I’d prefer a `JOIN` on the parent table and pass my parameters to the main query. `JOIN`s generally perform better, as they allow the DB to optimize the execution plan. A subquery is never optimized to the context of the outer query.